# Wordpress ajax request returns 0 in my infinite scroll script

Tags: ajax, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'd like to implement a very customized infinite scroll. But that comes later, cause i'm already stuck at the ajax request. What's wrong with my code (i get alwas a '0' response even though i have die() in the php function and added *nopriv* ...)??

my header.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 2;
var total = <?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>;
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if  (jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()){
        if (count > total){
            return false;
        }else{
           loadArticle(count);
           //viewsite();
        }
        count++;
    }
}); 

function loadArticle(pageNumber) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type:'POST',
        data: {
                action: 'ozinfinite_scroll',
                page_no: pageNumber
            },
        success: function(html){
            jQuery("#inf-cont-1").append(html);   

        }
    });
    return false;
}

</script>
```

functions.php:

```
function ozinfinite_scroll(){
  //  $loopFile        = $_POST['loop_file'];
    $paged           = $_POST['page_no'];
    $posts_per_page  = get_option('posts_per_page');

    # Load the posts
    query_posts(array('paged' => $paged ));
    get_template_part( 'contentoz', 'blog' );
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ozinfinite_scroll', 'ozinfinite_scroll');           // for logged in user
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ozinfinite_scroll', 'ozinfinite_scroll');    // if user not logged in

function add_ajaxurl_cdata_to_front(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
        ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    //]]> </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ajaxurl_cdata_to_front', 1);
```

thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm also experiencing this  - it's with the Underscores theme - what theme are you using?

Comment: I've solved my issue by using a different approach - I followed the tutorial here http://wptheming.com/2012/03/infinite-scroll-to-wordpress-theme/ I'm not sure if this will be helpful for you as it's a different approach but you may be able to try it out and extend on it for your own custom functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

you should have something like

```
echo $someValue
```

before wp_die() or die()

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Just for test purposes i replaced the content of the function with `$someValue = 1;  echo $someValue; die();` . I still get 0

Comment: try to enable debug and see if there is anything in debug.log